# Solving $5\cos^2y+x^2-2x\cos y-8x+20=0$

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me with this equation, i need find all $x,y \in \ R $  which satisfy equation

$$5\cos^2y+x^2-2x\cos y-8x+20=0  $$

Comment: I am just curious, where does this question come from?

Comment: i tried to pair x and cosy but i have nothing

Comment: What do you mean "find all $x$, $y$"? There will generally be uncountably many solutions to an equation like this. Do you hope to parametrize them all explicitly in terms of some independent variables $u$ and $v$? Or perhaps just to describe in words what shape the surface has?

Comment: @alex.jordan There is actually only one possible value of $x$ and countably many possible $y$.  See my answer.

Comment: Regarding my last comment, @Goos's answer demonstrates there is something special about this particular equation that reduces the number of real solutions from uncountably many to just countably many. I would guess that a parametrization of the solution set over $\mathbb{Z}$ is what is sought after.

Comment: i dont know how to translate from serbian to english... it says find all whatever professor think

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** The equation can be rewritten as
$$
\frac15 (5 \cos y - x)^2 + \frac45 (x - 5)^2 = 0
$$

Comment: thank you, i didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=\cos y$ and you have a conic section equation in $x$ and $z$: $$x^2+5z^2-2xz-8x+20=0$$ Since this is homework, maybe you have been shown a standard technique to describe this conic section? Or to parametrize it so that you have an explicit construction of it in terms of $u$ and $v$? Once you have done that, you can account for all of the solutions for $y$ in $z=\cos y$ to get a final parametrization of the original surface. (I'm not saying too much since this is homework.)